# 質問の(markdown)ソースを見るのに良い方法は？

Tags: サポート

時々 `<tag>タグ</tag>` が markdown に，コード用にクオートされずに含まれていて見えなくなってしまっている質問を見かけることがあります．これに限らず，質問のソースを見たいということはたまにある，と思います．これについてはなにか想定された手順がありますか（ないなら欲しい）．というのも，今のところ3種類のやり方 -- i) 編集， ii) 編集日時のリンクから revisions に飛ぶ， iii) revisions の url を直接叩く --- を知っているのですが，それぞれ問題があります:

---

i) 編集，について

一番簡便な方法としてよく使うのですが，例えば「別の人が送った承認待ちの編集」があるとき，質問の下にある「編集」のところはクリックできなくなります:

[image: この投稿には、別の承認待ちの編集があります。承認待ちの編集がレビューされるまで、追加の編集を送信できません。]

ii) また，編集履歴のない質問では（編集日時:のところのように）クリックできる `revisions` へのリンクは無いようです．

iii) 直に飛ぶ方法として，`ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/<id>/<title>` を `ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/<id>/revisions` に書き換えれば見に行けますが，大分面倒．

---

なにか良い方法はありますか．

Comment: いつも編集をクリックして行っています。それを使えないケースは稀にしか当たらないが、どの頻度でこの問題がありますか？

Comment: @jmac 個人的に出会ったのは (stack exchange の他のサイトを含めて）今回がはじめてです．「別の承認待ちの編集」があるとき，というのを考えてもそれほど多いとは思えないので， 頻度は十分に低いだろうと思います（won't fix であっても納得できます）．